# How to download & install .apk file in Android application?

Tags: android

I have one java Web Application through this application I am sending the URL to download the .apk file.now I have to use this URL in my Android Simulator browser to download .apk file and install automatically.
So can anyone please give me the solutions to this problems?

Comment: type the url in browser it will download and then you can install it

Comment: I want to install the .apk file automatically after completing the downloading.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4969421/1075066

Answer (score 3):

Just do these step:

1, Download file use Asynctask or Service. Solution [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/1050058)

2, Pass downloaded file to package installer.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

startActivity(intent);
```

It's simple set path to downloaded file and mime type. More detail **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)**. You can also look to the right. There is a list of related questions like  yours

Comment: After you install it, is there a way to re-launch the application? Right now it just returns to the home screen and you have to manually re-launch it.

Answer (score 0):

In browser type url and press enter ,it will ask to install. But file automatically installation process is basing on Device. If you go for Htc mobile It will be automatically installed but not for samsung mobiles

Comment: I am talking about Android Simulator 2.2 not mobile?